# Dummit and Foote Abstract Algebra 0.3 Exercise 8

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that the equation $a^2 + b^2 = 3c^2$ has no solutions in nonzero integers a,b,and c. [Consider the equation mod 4 to show that a,b, and c would all have to be divisible by 2. Then each of $a^2, b^2,$ and $c^2$ has a factor of four and by dividing through by 4 show that there would be a smaller set of solutions to the original equation. Iterate to reach a contracdiction.]

I’m having some trouble with this one. What does consider the equation mod 4 mean. I know what mod 4 means. Can someone explain how we can consider an equation mod 4 and how considering it mod 4 still keeps solutions consistent.

Thanks!

Comment: where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 4):

"Consider the equation mod $4$" means take the mod $4$ of both sides. If two numbers are equal, they must also be congruent mod $4$.

Comment: $(a^2+b^2) mod 4 = 3 c^2 mod 4$

Comment: @KalebAllinson Exactly. Now use the fact that a square is always congruent to $0$ or $1$ mod $4$. (If you haven't seen this fact before, think about why.)

Comment: Hmmm... the set of {a€Z} a mod 4 are 0,1,2,3 mod four. Is there a rule if a = k mod n then $a^2 =k^2$ mod n and then $a^2 = 0^2, 1^2, 2^2, 3^2$ mod 4 = 0,1,4,9 mod 4 = 0,1 mod 4?

Comment: @KalebAllinson Exactly! (In general, addition and multiplication both carry through mod 4, so if $a \equiv b$ mod 4 and $c \equiv d$ mod 4, then $a+c \equiv b+d$ mod 4 and $ac \equiv bd$ mod 4. The squaring rule you gave is a special case of multiplication.)

Comment: Great, then adding two squares a and b would be either 0+1 or 1+1 or 1+0 or 0+0 or 0,1,2 mod 4. And 3 times a square would be 3*0 or 3*1 = 0,3 mod 4. Both must be 0 mod 4 to be equal meaning both sides must be evenly divisible by 4.

Comment: C must be divisible by 2 for $c^2$ to be divisible by 4.

Comment: If $a^2+b^2$ is 0 mod 4, then it must be that $a^2 = 0$ mod 4 and $b^2 = 0$ mod 4 in order for them to add to 0 mod 4. Likewise a and b must be must be divisible by 2 in order for $a^2$ and $b^2$ to be divisible by 4.

Comment: Not sure where to go next.

Comment: $\frac{a^2+b^2}{4}=\frac{3c^2}{4} == (\frac{a}{2})^2+(\frac{b}{2})^2=3(\frac{c}{2})^2$

Comment: Then I guess the next numbers must also be divisible by 2 and so on forever. Since this is not possible, there are no solutions. Contradiction?

Comment: @KalebAllinson Perfect.